# How to make concat task fail on error?

Tags: ant, build.xml

```
<concat destfile="${destFile}" fixlastline="yes">
    <filelist dir="." files="${filelist}"/>
</concat>
```

In the fragment above I would like `concat` task to fail when a file from `filelist` isn't accessible/located. What would be the best way to implement it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve the same - but by defining the filelist before the concat, and checking whether the files are present.

Outline:

- Create a filelist with an id.
- Create a similar fileset from the same list of files.
- Get the count of resources in each of these - filesets only select files that exist.
- Compare the resource counts - if they differ some of the files don't exist.

A [`fail` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html) with embedded [condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) is used to compare the counts.  If this passes, the concat is carried out.

```
<filelist id="my.list" dir="." files="${filelist}" />
<fileset id="my.set" dir="." includes="${filelist}" />
<resourcecount refid="my.list" property="my.list.size" />
<resourcecount refid="my.set" property="my.set.size" />
<fail message="Only found ${my.set.size}/${my.list.size} files for concat!">
    <condition>
        <not>
            <equals arg1="${my.set.size}" arg2="${my.list.size}" />
        </not>
    </condition>
</fail>

<concat destfile="${destFile}" fixlastline="yes">
    <filelist refid="my.list" />
</concat>
```

To get the missing file list, use something like:

```
<difference id="missing">
    <resources refid="my.list"/>
    <resources refid="my.set"/>
</difference>
```

Then you can revise the `fail` task to:

```
<fail message="Missing files for concat: ${ant.refid:missing}">
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to be more informative (for example, printing the missing files' list) etc?